# My Broadcast Receiver class not gets called

Tags: android, arraylist, collections, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am trying to start an intent service from one activity which gets data from server and try to get that data in another activity using broadcast receiver but the broadcast receiver class is not getting called, I have registered my service class in manifest also

Here is my code to start a service

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MyWebRequestService.class); 
 startService(intent);
```

Class MyWebRequestService

```
//inside on handle intent
new AsynchCall().execute();
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction(MyWebRequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
//here I am getting the data in my arraylist
broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("namelist", servicelist);
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Activity where I want to receive my data

```
IntentFilter filter =IntentFilter(MyWebRequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
receiver = new MyWebRequestReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

In the same activity I have written my broadcast receiver class

```
public class MyWebRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  public static final String PROCESS_RESPONS = "com.rentpro.PROCESS_RESPONSE";

    @Override   
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {   
       listofnames = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("namelist");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the receiver

```
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

is called before sending the broadcast

```
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Comment: Also make sure your app doesn't leak the receiver by calling `unregisterReceiver()` preferably in your activity's `onPause()` method.

Comment: yes i had call this in onPause already but how it is possible to call registerReceiver(receiver, filter) before sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent); in my case i had refer this link [link](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html)